# cakephp The eventKey variable is required

Tags: cakephp

I'm getting the following error message on all my pages in cakePHP:

```
The eventKey variable is required
```

Does anyone know what this is and how to get this fixed? 
I have no clue where it comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you googled this error? I seem to get a lot of relevant results if I try... If so, please add more information about what you are doing, what have you changed to make the error pop up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check for an empty `Construct { }` in your models

Comment: you actually need to add parent::__construct(); on the first line of your __construct method, thats if you need a constructor. If you dont need it, then remove the __construct method.

Answer (score 0):

**It can be naming function too.**

When function name is similar/like model name, my example:

model **ProfileFriend**,
function: function **profileFriend()**{...}
use: **$this->ProfileFriend->profileFriend()**;

Yeah I know, my function name looks weird when I write model name before function name, but when my code look like this:

```
    $model = $this->modelClass;
    // ....
    $is_friend = $this->$model->profileFriend();

    // ...
```

... then my function name doesn't looks so weird.